# How to compare dates one with time zone and one without time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to compare the two dates to get the last 10 min records from database,I'm using postgresql,

I have write this query

```
select *
FROM x_table 
WHERE x_time >= (NOW()::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE - interval '10 minutes');
```

x_time is timestamp without time zone so that's why i'm converting the other to the same but it won't giving the result.

Query should written the last 1 min records  but i think due to time zone issue it is not giving the result.

how can i resolve the issue?

Comment: show us `select max(x_time), NOW()::TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE from x_table`?..

Comment: this will give following result  '2017-02-09 14:41:11.828966','2017-02-09 05:46:55.253082'

Comment: then I suppose you should not implicitely convert now() - just use `select *FROM x_table WHERE x_time >= (NOW() - interval '10 minutes');`

Comment: Yes i have tried that first but as these both will give me time in different format and i'm comparing them will not give the right result

Comment: if you populated your `timestamp without time zone` field with data - it is save with current timezone, not UTC, so if you select it with same time zone, you don't have to do any conversions

Comment: Vao Rsun it's working for the some cases but when i'm running this query and i'm not having any record for last 1 but still it returning the records                                          SELECT *  FROM x_table WHERE (x_time) >= (Now() - interval '1 minutes')

Answer (score 1):

If x_time is timestamp without time zone, you should specify proper time zone for NOW() function.

Try

```
select *FROM x_table WHERE x_time >= (NOW()  at time zone '-04' - interval '10 minutes')
```

Comment: I'm sorry. How about `(NOW()  at time zone '-04' - interval '10 minutes')`? It's almost 15:00 there and I see your max(t_time) was 14:41 several minutes ago.

Comment: could you mark it as answer? I've edited my first post